Query using two variable in two array
Please refer to my google sheet in this link.
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1cuNkoR4Rn7Lt0u-aCB4487JnucMKYgx0ETn6R_w7-ds/edit?usp=sharing
I want to query the original data, using the combination of two values in column 1 of the original data. The number of rows in original data may vary. The combination array is calculated using the Cartesian product, and has been handled by formula.
For every combination queried, a separator row is inserted and so on.  The anticipated outcome is shown in expected data.
I tried using lambda and query (shown in cell M3). I also tried using filter and index, all of which appear did not accept the array value as input.
I seek your professional advice and input. Thank you.
Original Data



Col1
Col2
Col3
Col4
Col5




A
aawek
ert
gh
dsfg


B
asfdklj
vnv
ghc
dfgs


D
sadf
dsfg
sfdg
hgdfh


E
erty
dfsg
sdfg
gfhre


F
tyher
dsfg
sdfg
dfsg



Combination of Col1



1
2




A
B


A
D


A
E


A
F


B
D


B
E


B
F


D
E


D
F


E
F



Expected Data



Col1
Col2
Col3
Col4
Col5




A
aawek
ert
gh
dsfg


B
asfdklj
vnv
ghc
dfgs


*****
*****
*****
*****
*****


A
aawek
ert
gh
dsfg


D
sadf
dsfg
sfdg
hgdfh


*****
*****
*****
*****
*****


A
aawek
ert
gh
dsfg


E
erty
dfsg
sdfg
gfhre


*****
*****
*****
*****
*****


A
aawek
ert
gh
dsfg


F
tyher
dsfg
sdfg
dfsg


*****
*****
*****
*****
*****


....
....
....
....
....


....
....
....
....
....



Tried function
=arrayformula(lambda(x,y,query(A3:E8,"select * where Col1='"&X&"' or Col1='"&Y&"'",1))(A13:A22,B13:B22  ))



You may try:
=let(Σ,filter(A13:B,A13:A<>""),Λ,A4:E8,
     reduce(tocol(,1),sequence(rows(Σ)),lambda(a,c,vstack(a,filter(Λ,xmatch(choosecols(Λ,1),chooserows(Σ,c))),wraprows(rept("*",5),columns(Λ),rept("*",5))))))



Hi @rockinfreakshow, I found that when the combination table (A13:B) only have one row, the combination could not be shown. After various attempt to fix the issue, effort was in vain.  I put up a new post and hope you can extend your help, thanks.
link

Updated; one change of index to chooserows done

Thanks @rockinfreakshow, I don't understand this part '...xmatch(choosecols(Λ,1),chooserows(Σ,c))...'.  From the google sheet documentation and example on the internet, the first two parameter should be of the same length and direction (both are rows/ columns).  Can you explain more if you have time?  Thanks!

In the first iteration it loosely translates to xmatch(A3:A8,A13:B13) & in the next iteration it becomes xmatch(A3:A8,A14:B14) and so on...; the number of iterations depend on the value assigned by this part here sequence(rows(Σ))
